# Prove that a monotonically increasing continuous function is invertible.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow[f(a),f(b)]$ be strictly increasing continuous function (i.e $x>y \implies f(x)>f(y)$). Prove that f is invertible.

Proving that the function is one-to-one was simple enough. I need some guidance on proving it's onto. I'm new to $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs since I just started self-studying some metric spaces.

Comment: Apply the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: Fix $d$ in $(f(a),f(b))$ and suppose there is no $c$ in [a,b] such that $f(c)=d$ and try to contradicts continuity using the other hypothesis

Comment: Since $[a,b]$ is connected, and $f$ is continuous, then $f([a,b])$ is connected. Connected subsets of the real line are intervals. Since $f$ is monotonic, we have $f([a,b]) = [f(a),f(b)]$.

Comment: BTW this question gives kind of converse statement: [A continuous, injective function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170147/a-continuous-injective-function-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-is-either-strict).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y \in (f(a), f(b))$ and let $A = \{ x \in [a, b] : f(x) < y\}$.  Since A is nonempty, and $A \subset [a, b]$,  $s =\sup A$ exists.  To show that $f(s) = y$, choose a sequence $x_n \in A$ that converges to $s$.  Since we have $s \in [a, b]$, and by continuity,

$$f(s) = \lim_{n \to \infty}f(x_n) \le y$$

By contradiction, suppose $f(s) < y$.  Then $y - f(x)$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, and $y - f(s) > 0$.  We can choose $\delta > 0$ and $u > s$ such that $y-f(u) > \delta$, but this implies that $u \in A$, a contradiction.