# A continuous function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is injective if and only if it is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Is the following statement true?

> A continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is injective if and only if $f$ is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.
>
> If it's true give a proof. If it's false give a counter-example.

I think the answer is false but I just can't think of a counter-example. Any help would be useful.

Comment: Is $f$ assumed continuous?

Comment: Sorry my bad. Yes function is continuous

Comment: One direction should be almost obvious, the other should follow from the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem). See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170147/a-continuous-injective-function-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-is-either-strict).

Comment: Wait, so the statement is true?

Comment: @Pablo yes, it is

Comment: Thanks Everyone!!! I got a little bit confused because the answer in my book said it was false but didn't give a counter-example. Really appreciate the help!!

Comment: What's the book?!