# Show that function is injective and surjective using given condition on $f$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Consider $f$ a continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

It is given that $$|f(x)-f(y)|\geq \frac{1}{2}|x-y|\tag{1}$$ for all $x,y$ in $\mathbb{R}$

***I want to show that $f$ is one-one and onto***

**My efforts**

**Injectivity**

Suppose $a,b\in \mathbb{R}\text{ and } a\neq b$ such that $f(a)=f(b).$

Then consider the following fraction $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ which is equal to zero as $f(b)=f(a)$ and $b\neq a$

But that is a contradiction as given condition on $f$ says that $|f(b)-f(a)|\geq \frac{1}{2}|b-a|$ and that would actually show that $0\geq \frac{1}{2}|b-a|$ and right hand side is strictly greater than zero.

***Therefore function is one one.***

**Surjectivity**

Let $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ be any arbitrary point and WLOG assume $x_0\geq 0$.

If I put $y=0$ condition (1) says $f(x)\geq \frac{1}{2}x+f(0)$ if $x\geq 0$ (also using the fact that WLOG that function is increasing).

Take $x=2x_0$,

we have $f(2x_0)\geq x_0 +f(0)$

Take $x=-2x_0$ and then we have $f(-2x_0)\leq x_0-f(0)$

So we have $f(-2x_0)\leq x_0-f(0)\leq x_0\leq x_0+f(0)\leq f(2x_0)$

Now Intermediate Value theorem works like a magic and we are done!!!!

Am I correct?

Edit: If people are confused, why I can assume that function is increasing in surjectivity part, here is the answer [A continuous, injective function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170147/a-continuous-injective-function-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-is-either-strict)

Comment: logic is impeccable

Comment: Injectivity should be simpler:  $f(a)=f(b)$ implies $0=|f(a) - f(b)| \geq \frac{1}{2}|a-b|$ forces $a=b$.

Comment: I think I have used the same logic but in a slightly different way. @Randall

Comment: I agree:  it's pretty close.

Answer (score -1):

The proof doesn't seem to be right, for example, f(x)=-x will make the proof fail.

The conclusion is correct, though: since R is connected, so is the image of f(x). In other words, the image fills a chuck of R. The only thing we need to prove is f(x) is unbounded, which follows immediately from the inequality with y=0.

Comment: Can you please point out at which it fails?

Comment: For x>0, f(x)<0<x. Maybe the proof lost the absolute signs.

Comment: But WLOG we may assume that function is monotonically increasing. If it is not we can just reverse the inequalities.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would be monotonical. The proof wouldn't be trivial.

Comment: Okay, after a quick thought, f(x) is monotonical. Then, the proof shall state that.

Comment: A continuous, injective function f:R→R
is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170147/a-continuous-injective-function-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-is-either-strict  If you want a proof please have a look at it.

Comment: I have edited the post as well and added the link in case other want to have a look.