# How can I prove that some functions are injective?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, functions

Definition of an injective function

$$ f(x_1) = f(x_2) => x_1 = x_2 $$

Well I have two functions that I can't prove...

$$ f(x) = x^3 + x $$
$$ f(x) = \frac{x}{1-log(x)} $$
log(x) denotes the logarithm base 10 function, well it doesn't matter for this problem, but whatever.

the first function
$$ x_1^3 + x_1 = x_2^3 + x_2 $$
What can I do after this? Same with the second function, how can I manipulate in order to achieve $$ x_1 = x_2 $$

Comment: Your first $f$ is increasing.

Comment: and your second $f$ doesn't appear to be injective

Comment: Hmmm, so If I prove that a function is monotonic increasing/decreasing) on its domain.... always increasing and is continuous then it's injective?

Yes I saw later, the second isn't

Comment: @NunoMateus: yes, if its strictly increasing or decreasing, it's injective

Comment: What you have given are no functions at all. You are missing to tell what the domain and codomain is. You should give functions as $f: X\to Y$ with $x\mapsto f(x)$. That is espacially important when you are talking about properties like injective and surjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume your functions are defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

As noted in the comments, instead of using the definition of injective you have given, we can make use of the fact that the first function is *strictly increasing*.

This means, precisely, that

$$x > y \implies f(x) > f(y) \space \space \space (\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R})$$

To show that $f$ is increasing we can show that its derivative is always positive.

$\frac{df}{dx} = 3x^2 + 1$ which is clearly positive for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Alternatively, without using calculus but making some smaller assumptions we can do this:

Assume $x>y$. Then, cubing both sides and noting that the cube function is itself strictly increasing, we have

$$x^3 > y^3$$

and then adding $x$ to one side and $y$ to the other (since $x>y$ this is valid)

$$x^3 + x > y^3 + y$$

$$f(x) > f(y)$$

and we are done.

Since $f$ is strictly increasing, it is injective.

Comment: Did you mean $x>y\implies x^3>y^3$ and so $x^3+x>y^3+y$ ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes! Silly me.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one: $$ x_1^3 + x_1 = x_2^3 + x_2 \rightarrow x_1^3-x_2^3+ x_1-x_2=0 \rightarrow (x_1 - x_2)(x_1^2+x_1 \cdot x_2+x_2^2+1)=0 \rightarrow x_1 - x_2=0$$ (the second term does not have real roots, discriminant is $x_2^2-4x_2^2-4<0)$

The second function is not injective.

Answer (score 1):

To provide an alternate way of showing injectivity for differentiable functions, every strictly increasing (or decreasing) function is injective (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170147/a-continuous-injective-function-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-is-either-strict) for a proof).

To show that a function is strictly increasing, show that its derivative is always positive. For example, for your first function, $f '(x) = 3x^2 + 1$, which is positive for any value of $x$. Therefore, the function is injective.