# Prove that the function $ g $ satisfying $g(g(x))=2g(x)-x $ is strictly monotonic.

Tags: monotone-functions

Let $ g :\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ a continuous function such that
$$(\forall x\in \Bbb R)\; g(g(x))=2g(x)-x$$

Prove that $ g $ is injective and strictly monotonic.

I took $ x,y\in \Bbb R $.
$$g(x)=g(y)\implies g(g(x))=g(g(y))$$
$$\implies 2g(x)-x=2g(y)-y $$
$$\implies x=y$$

but to show that it is strictly monotonic,
I didn't find a simple answer.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: An injective continuous function must be ...?

Comment: Is this a theorem ?

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I don't think it has a name but it is not hard to prove. Injectivity implies that that it is locally monotonic, continuity ensures that it isn't a crooked step function that changes direction on certain intervals. See if you can make that description precise.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170147/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Continuous $1-1$ function $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R} $ is strictly monotone.

Hint:**(Use Intermediate value theorem)**

Strategy:

Assume $f$ is not strictly monotone.

Then, there exists $ x,y,z\in \Bbb{R}$  with $ x<y<z $ such that either:

$f(x)\le f(y)\ge f(z)$

Or

$f(x)\ge f(y) \le f(z) $

Now ignore the equality between all of them otherwise it fails to be one-to-one.

Now use intermediate value theorem  to contradict that $f$ is one -to-one.