# Prove that a continuous one-to-one function is either increasing or decreasing strictly.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, solution-verification, continuity

I'm an autodidact, and so, I really doubt sometimes if my solutions, especially in Analysis, are correct or not. Here is the theorem I have to prove:

**If $f$ is a one-to-one continuous function on an interval $I$. Then $f$ is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing**

Proof: Let $f : [a,b] \to \mathcal{R}$. Consider $x_1, x_2 \in [a,b]$ such that $x_2> x_1$.
$f(x_1) = f(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$ by the virtue of one-to-one, therefore it is not possible. The only two remaining possibilities are:
$f(x_1) > f(x_2)$, or
$f(x_2) > f(x_1)$
As $x_1 ~\text{and}~x_2$ were arbitrary, therefore the above working shows, that either $f$ is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing.

Was I rigorous enough in my proof?

P.S.: Let me know how many questions am I allowed per week (or other duration) to post in "solution verification" tag, because these types questions shall not be contributing to the real aim of the site.

Comment: It does not prove then result. You just proved that **for fixed $x_1$ and $x_2$** either $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$ or $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$. This is the definition of a monotone function.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170147/42969 for better proofs

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't.

You must also prove that the direction of the inequality is always the same.

*Hint*: Use  two intervals $[x_1,x_2]$ and $[x_2,x_3]$ and intermediate value theorem for continuous functions.

Comment: If we assume CASE 1: that for $x_1 \lt x_2$ we have $f(x_1) \lt f(x_2)$. Then, by IVT for every $x$ in $x_1 \lt x \lt x_2 $ we have $f(x_1) \lt f(x) \lt f(x_2)$. But does that imply for every $x \lt x_2$ we have $f(x) \lt f(x_2)$?